# After a while of use USB device not detected

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have win 7 ultimate on my Acer 6492 laptop. When its booted up, USB devices plugged in work just fine. After a while (probably an hour or so) these same devices will not be detected by the laptop. If the laptop is rebooted, then it would start working fine.

Devices used are mobile phones, USB data modems.

I have not done a virus scan because didn't think it would be related to that. I also have not tried any restore points. Neither have I re-installed USB drivers. I haven't been sure.

I'd like some advise.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the device manager? You can do that via `devmgmt.msc` and clicking `Scan for hardware changes`. In my experience, my Galaxy S3 has this odd behaviour whereby it won't get detected by my PC unless I unlock it first.

Comment: Hi,  I'll try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of USB are you using? if it is USB 3.0 try to update the drivers or install them again. 
If it is USB 2.0 rigth click on MyComputer-->manage-->left pane u have Device manager.
uninstall drivers over there. and restart PC. by default USB 2.0 drivers will be installed automatically after you boot your PC. and then try now if it resolves your problem. this might work.

Comment: I uninstalled all usb drivers. On reboot all problems solved. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite solve the problem. I thought it had but after a while it does not recognize my phone.

Comment: since how many days are you getting this problem?

Comment: It's been a while. Few months before I decided to fix it.

Comment: if you remember the day you started getting the problem, go to system restore point and restore it. warning: if you restore say example to the date 15th aug 2013 programs installed after that date will be lost   ,just programs. your data wil be safe.

Answer (score -1):

Probably your Pen Drive File System is corrupted.

Do a complete format procedure using DiskPart Utility in Windows CMD.
With clean and making new partition on it.

or

If its your computer as you say,
Not good to leave your devices plugged in, when pc on sleep, hibernate.

That should solve the problem.